# latex theorem does not wrap text in 2-column

Tags: latex

The following latex code produces a definition that its text overlaps to the 2nd column. The ijcai18 package makes it a 2-column article, so perhaps the problem is there ? I do not know how to read it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ijcai18}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]    
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition} [This is a long definition title that does not wrap to the next line]

...
\end{definition}
\lipsum[1-5]    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ijcai18` conference style](http://www.ijcai.org/authors_kit) does not add any theorem-related functionality. As such, `\newtheorem{definition}[.]{Definition}` still relies on LaTeX's original definition for creating the theorem-like environments.

In LaTeX, theorems as defined via `\newtheorem` is set as a *list*, with the entire theorem consisting of a singular `\item`. The title of the theorem is passed as the optional argument to `\item` (that is, `\item[<theorem title stuff>]`, and this optional argument is set inside a box that doesn't allow for line-breaking.

Below I redefine the part that sets the `\item` specifically for a theorem that has an optional argument (like in your case, `\begin{definition}[..]`). Here's the original definition (from the [LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co)):

```
\def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{\trivlist
  \item[\hskip \labelsep{\bfseries #1\ #2\ (#3)}]\itshape}
```

[image]

and here's the changed definition:

```
\def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{\trivlist
   \item[]{\bfseries #1\ #2\ (#3)} \itshape}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ijcai18}% http://www.ijcai.org/authors_kit
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\makeatletter
\def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{\trivlist
   \item[]{\bfseries #1\ #2\ (#3)} \itshape}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[This is a long definition title that does not wrap to the next line]
\lipsum[1]
\end{definition}

\lipsum[2-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Forever grateful! it solved the problem. They should change the ijcar package.

Comment: @Oferstrichman: Consider *accepting* this answer then. See [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)